7-1/2 single phase, 230V, induction(?), centrifugal switch equipped Compressor Motor NOT starting
I'm stuck, I've got a 7-1/2 single phase, 230V, induction(?), centrifugal-switch-equipped Compressor Motor NOT starting.  (I put a question mark after "induction" because that's an assumption on my part because I'm not overly familiar with electric motors).
Compressor: Ingersoll Rand 2-stage model 2475
Motor: WEG (Ingersoll Rand part number: 32309437)
Initial Problem: Compressor would start first time and run normally until full (roughly 175 psi).  Subsequently, when the compressor tried to restart at the low end of the pressure switch setting (roughly 145 psi) I'd hear the unit attempt to start, and it would then trip the breaker at the main panel.  Prior to this problem I had noticed that the centrifugal switch would spark on startup.
I did two things to attempt a repair: (1) checked the start capacitors and replaced one that was obviously ruined (the smaller 189 - 250 μF capacitor); and (2) opened the motor and cleaned the centrifugal switch contacts.
On the first startup after the "repair" the compressor started fine and run up to full pressure.  Restart failed - if I remember correctly, it tripped the breaker, but I don't remember if it simply buzzed and I shut it off (in case this matters).  Now the unit won't start at all - even with relatively low pressure in the tank - around 130 psi.  I have checked both the pressure switch pressure-relief and the tank check valve - both are fine so the problem is not with the air system.
My current hypothesis is that I accidentally mixed up a wire in either the start capacitor bank (three capacitors) or the run capacitor bank (two capacitors), or the wiring to the centrifugal switch.  If this hypothesis is correct, the reason the motor started the first time after repair is because the rotor just happened to be in a position where the motor fired off without the aid of the starting capacitor circuit.
I'll attach a labelled photograph of the capacitor bank with additional notes:

There are six wires coming from the motor:
Two are unlabelled which I assume are coming from the centrifugal switch [terminals 1 & 2]
Two going to the main winding (labelled: 1 U1, and 4 U2)
Two going to the start winding (labelled 5 V2 [terminal #6], and 8 V5 [terminal 5])
NOTE: V2 is connected to terminal 6 in the picture, and V5 [coincidentally] is connected to terminal 5 in the picture.
All of the above are assumptions on my part (i.e. main winding, start winding, centrifugal switch, but they do seem to correlate with descriptions I've found online)
The start capacitors are wired in parallel and measure 669 μF (i.e. 189-250 μF + 216-259 μF + 216-259 μF = 621 μF - 768 μF range so 669 μF measured at terminals #1 & #2 in the attached picture (with the respective wires disconnected) sounds about right.
Similarly, there are two 30 μF capacitors that appear to be wired in parallel which should in theory provide 60 μF of run capacitance, although I haven't measured this yet.
Where I'm stuck is I don't understand why the start circuit is connected to the run capacitors, and how the start capacitors drop out after the switch opens.  Genuinely confused, but it almost seems that the start capacitor bank is connected in SERIES with the first run capacitor which would drop the overall start capacitor banks down to something like 58 μF (669 μF from the above three in parallel connected to one run capacitor at 30 μF would only produce 28.7 μF which would explain the non-start behavior).  Again, I'm confused on the wiring in the area of terminals marked 2, 3, and 4 in the attached picture.  And, don't really understand how this all fits in with the start windings being wired (V2 at terminal #6 and V5 wired at #6).
It would be great if someone could "sore thumb" the capacitor and switch wiring, and possibly suggest other things to check.
More on point, did I inadvertently mix up one or two of the wires when initially testing all of the capacitors?  I was very careful labelling and replacing wires one capacitor at a time, but something isn't right, or still no functioning given the no-start.
